# UICollectionView rearranging , horizontal displacement

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

The normal way to implement the rearrange functionality of a UICollection is to do something like the following:

Inside, say, viewDidLoad:

```
    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongPress(gesture:)))
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.2
    self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

then the handleLongPress function:

```
func handleLongPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    switch(gesture.state){
    case .began:
        guard let selected = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)) else{
            break
        }
        self.collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selected)
    case .changed:
        self.collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
    case .ended:
        self.collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
    default:
        self.collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

and implement

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool { ... }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) { ... }
```

This makes such that I can long press anywhere on a cell.  However, when I long press on the far right or far left side, the cell centers on where my touch was.  Can I disable the centering functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    case .changed:
        var location:CGPoint = gesture.location(in: gesture.view!)
        location.x = self.collectionView.frame.midX
        self.collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(location)
```

was all i ended up needing